# Positioning tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get the text to position in the center of the image.

```
<table width="261" height="253" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 5px; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; letter-spacing: 0px; word-spacing: 0px; background-image: none; background-repeat: repeat; background-position: 0% 0%; height: 235px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 0px;">
        <p> 
          <table width="" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 40px; width: 189px; height: 121px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><span style="font-family: Tahoma;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem Ipsum</span> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer </span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table><img src="/resource/resmgr/boxes/box_connect2.png" title="" alt="" /></p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't use tables for layout purposes.  If you want to use the behavior for vertical centering, use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` on non-table elements.

Answer (score 1):

First off, get your CSS out of inline and into a proper CSS file.

Here is the clean up and one possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/UD2XV/

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="outer_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="outer_td">

          <table width="" cellpadding="0" class="inner_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="inner_text">Lorem Ipsum</span> 
                    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
                    the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <img src="/resource/resmgr/boxes/box_connect2.png" title="" alt="" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer_table { width:261px; height:253px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left;}

.inner_table{border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 40px; width: 189px; height: 121px; text-align:center;}

.outer_td {vertical-align: top; letter-spacing: 0px; word-spacing: 0px; background-image: none; background-repeat: repeat; background-position: 0% 0%; height: 235px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 0px;}

.inner_td{font-family: Tahoma;}

.inner_text {font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma;}
```

Comment: While you were at it, you should have shown how to do this without using the `table` element.

Comment: I thought about it, but looking at the code it looks the OP is a beginner.  I didn't want to go outside of the scope of the question too much as it may have confused more than helped.